# Downloading a file from a link address using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was able to download the CSV file from the link address but it gives me different data.

My question is. Is it possible to download the file from a link address without affecting its data, filename, and extension?

actual link https://bboxx.slack.com/stats/export?type=users&date_range=all&cols=name%2Cuser_id%2Cusername%2Cemail%2Caccount_type%2Caccount_created%2Cis_billable_seat%2Cdays_active%2Cchats_sent&sort_prefix=name&sort_dir=asc

This is the data that I get whenever I use the download link.
[image: Original file]

```
import requests
from slacker import Slacker
import wget
auth='xxxx', 'xxxxx'
slack = Slacker('xxxx')


url = 'https://bboxx.slack.com/stats/export?type=users&date_range=all&cols=name%2Cuser_id%2Cusername%2Cemail%2Caccount_type%2Caccount_created%2Cis_billable_seat%2Cdays_active%2Cchats_sent&sort_prefix=name&sort_dir=asc'

wget.download(url, 'C:/Users/IanJay/Desktop/asda.csv')
```

[image: MY OUTPUT]

.........

Comment: When you are doing `wget` from the code, you are not logged-in to slack. So the URl is redirecting to the log-in page of slack. Whose HTML & JS you are seeing in the csv file. You should login to slack first & then yoiu probably need to pass a cookie or token to make sure you are logged in while trying to download the file

Comment: When you say “I was able to download” I assume you mean using a web browser. The page you access probably runs some JavaScript in your browser. wget doesn’t process JavaScript so doesn’t perform the same behaviour.

Comment: Here is some help to connect to slack using a script : https://blog.pythian.com/logging-for-slackers/

Comment: Hi @rdas do you mind sharing any documentation on how to do it?

Comment: @PeterWood yes, I am using web browser when downloading using that link.
So its impossible to do this on python?

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Hi @PeterWood, I've used selenium but It does open up a browser.
I'm planning to run this code on a server. Is there's another lib on python that might do it?

Comment: You can run it headless.

Comment: https://realpython.com/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/